# draw values from 2nd column after matching 1st columns R

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I am trying to loop through two data frames and based on matching names, draw a value from the second data frame into the first. Right now my code looks like

```
for (n in 1:180){
    for (m in 1:180){
        if (league2008[n,1]==league2009[m,1]){
            league2008[n,23]=league2009[m,23]
            league2008[n,30]=league2009[m,30]
        }
    }
}
```

So right now, if the names in column 1 match, I bring column 23 and 30 value for that name from 2009 to 2008. THIS WORKS, but is there a way of doing this loop faster, and is there a way that I can name the columns instead of just giving their index? I would like to make my code more robust and change the columns in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this should work just fine:

```
n <- 1:180
m <- 1:180
ind <- expand.grid(n,m)
con <- league2008[ind[,1],1] == league2009[ind[,2],1]
league2008[ind[con,1],23] <- league2009[ind[con,2],23]
league2008[ind[con,1],30] <- league2009[ind[con,2],30]
```

**-- Explanation --**

This works, because we can supply a vector of indices to a vector/matrix/data frame. To illustrate:

```
a <- 1:10
a[1:5]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

We exploit this fact by creating every possible combination between `n` and `m` with `expand.grid(n,m)`. We then do `league2008[ind[,1],1] == league2009[ind[,2],1]`, which returns for every possible combination whether the condition is satisfied. We then subset `ind` for only those that return `TRUE` by doing `ind[con,]`.

Comment: Thank you! If I were to do this for several year pairings, would I have to reinitialize the grid or could I simply start with your conditional step again? m and n are the same number each year pairing so the grid would never need to change size I suppose

Comment: No problem. If `m` and `n` always stay the same, then their possible combinations won't change, so `ind` doesn't need to change either. If this answers all your questions, don't forget to press the checkmark next to my answer to close the question.